# Switching APC rack PDU via SNMP

Tags: snmp, electrical-power, power-distribution-unit, apc, snmpv3

How can I switch the outlets of an APC Rack PDU (AP7920) via SNMP (Linux SNMP command tools like snmpget/snmpset) ?

I can't find anything about it.

I was able to walk it via:

```
snmpwalk -v3 -a MD5 -A xxxxxxxxxxxxxx -u switch -x DES -X xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 192.168.1.1
```

but not to switch an outlet.

Comment: I’m guessing you’d need to use `snmpset` on some OID.

Comment: I think part of my question is what the OIDs are. I was not able to find information on them.

Answer (score 0):

Below OID works for me to control outlet #1, the last integer in this oid can be modified to n to control the nth outlet.

OID(powernet mib) - .1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.4.4.2.1.3.1

Integer values:
1 - Outlet ON,
2 - Outlet OFF,
3 - Outlet Reboot